# 'warrant' in the sense of guarantee, proof or confirmation

Tags: word-usage

*[I have edited my question: the formulation I first read and asked about was apparently paraphrasing a sentence from a book by an American scholar. Having used the footnote to find the original text, I replaced the citation with the original one, hopefully it could help].*

> These [two] labels refer respectively to experiences of present
>   self-authenticity as warrant for a self claim to an intrinsic
>   identity, and to actions of self authenticity as warrant for a self
>   claim to a moral life.

I am not sure, whether this use of **warrant** is grammatical, and what it means exactly, I've looked for it in the dictionary and found that warrant can be used in the senses of guarantee, proof or confirmation. Yet, another native-spaeker friend insisted that this sentence makes no sense and must be a typo or a mistake. Is it possible to use it this way?

Comment: I can't be sure without the context in which the sentence was written, but it appears to be a stylised way of conveying the point, and written out fully would have been "It has become a warrant for self-claims to moral life." A similar instance of this would be things like "I am become death". That's how I would interpret it, anyway.

Comment: It's certainly using "warrant" in an unfamiliar way, and you should not be ashamed to have not understood it.  Plus I cannot find a dictionary which defines "warrant" as an adjective, and the usage is not one where a claim to the validity of "adjectifying" a noun/verb would seem to stand up.

Comment: I can find no way of making it grammatical, and would suppose it to be a mistake.

Comment: Although "warrant" as a mass noun is usually used negatively, I think this is just a (correct) example of it being used positively to mean "authorization/justification/authority": "It has become justification for self-claims to moral life."

Comment: I suggest your "highly-educated native-speaker" *isn't*. Note that the *noun* usually used to mean *guarantee, proof or confirmation* is ***warranty***. Possibly what the speaker meant is *It has become the **trademark** for self-claims to moral life*, but to be honest I don't know exactly what *self-claims to moral life* is supposed to mean (it just makes me think whoever said that isn't even a native speaker at all, let alone a competent speaker).

Comment: Your question is a request for us to proof-read a sentence that doesn't seem to make sense. You need to ask the native speaker what the sentence means.

Comment: I suspect that it's just a typo; it should probaby be 'warrented'.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and suggestions. I have edited my question: the formulation I first read and asked about was apparently paraphrasing a sentence from a book by an American scholar. Having used the footnote to find the original text, I replaced the citation with the original one. Does it make any more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

'Warrant' can mean a token of authorization, a confirmation, or a justification (Webster's 10th College Dictionary), and if you substitute these terms for 'warrant' in the sentence provided, it makes sense.

Comment: +1 for mentioning this positive [mass/uncountable noun {def#3}](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/warrant) use of ‘warrant [for].’ The fact that your answer has been downvoted and that the OP’s good question has received closevotes as a mere request for proofreading is proof itself that this perfectly correct, albeit formal, use of ‘warrant’ is unfamiliar to enough native and non-native speakers alike to warrant its further discussion in this forum. This lack of familiarity by some is no warrant, nor should it ever become warrant for such criticism.

Comment: I'll warrant that's a good comment...